# Repeating a texture every 2 seconds in libGDX

Tags: android, eclipse, timer, libgdx, task

I am devloping a game in libgdx. I want some kind of a timer that says every 2 seconds draw a texture. I have searched the Internet but could not find any good help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to store a `float timer` and in the `render(float delta)` method you increase it by `delta`. If `timer` is bigger the 2 (`delta` is the time since last frame, in seconds), decrase the `timer` by 2 and `draw` your `Texture`.
Pseudocode:

```
public void render(float delta) {
    // Clear your Screen here
    timer+=delta;
    if (timer >= 2) {
        timer-=2;   // If you reset it to 0 you will loose a few milliseconds every 2 seconds.
        spriteBatch.draw(myTexture, position.x, position.y);
    }
 }
```

I suppose you know how to use `SpriteBatch` and `Texture`, if not look for it in the libgdx documentations.

**Edit:**
The `render()` method has a float delta in classes which implement `Screen` interface. You can access `delta` from everywhere using `Gdx.Graphics.getDeltaTime()` or `Gdx.Graphics.getRawDeltaTime`.
Raw Delta is the actual `delta`, while the "normal" delta time may be smoothed over n frames.

**Another Edit:**

I suppose you have all the position where you want to `draw()` a `Texture` stored in an `Array<Vector2> texPositions`. So the code you need would be the following (pseudocode, do not copy and paste but try to understand!):

```
 public void render(float delta) {
    // Clear your Screen here
    timer+=delta;
    if (timer >= 2) {
        timer-=2;   // If you reset it to 0 you will loose a few milliseconds every 2 seconds.
        spriteBatch.draw(myTexture, position.x, position.y);
        texPositions.add(new Vector2(position.x, position.y));
    }
    for (Vector2 texPos : texPositions) {
         // Modify the position.x of the Texture by 5*delta, it moves along the x-axis
         texPos.add(5*delta, 0);
         spriteBatch.draw(myTexture, texPos.x, texPos.y);
    }

 }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your comment. If i type float delta in render, i get error. My render method is Overrided.

Comment: You can use Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() instead

Comment: You must not be using a `Screen` class. Just add the line `float delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();` to the top of your render method.

Comment: Thankyou the code works, but not exactly how i wanted. After 2 seconds it draws the texture for only 0.1 seconds. then it disappears. what i really want is that after 2 seconds it must draw a texture and it must stay there and after another 2 seconds it must draw another same texture in the same place. My texture has a code that says move down. so if u understand its a game that textures start on the top and come down every 2 seconds. i hope you can help me with his one. Thanks

Comment: @user2959870 So let the code how it is and under the if add the `SpriteBatch.draw()` for your other `Texture`, at the position where it should be. I write some pseudocode in the answer